# How to change color of Toolbar back button in Android?

Tags: android

I could not change the color of back button. I am using toolbar material design. In my app I am applying black background of tool bar but the back design is being black by default that's why I just want to change the color of this back button. Please give me solutions.

Thank You

Comment: <style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

Answer (score 100, accepted):

use this style

```
<style name="Theme.MyFancyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/back_button_image</item>
</style>
```

Comment: i am using this style. what i have to change in this style?

Comment: you can use custom image files for back button.just call it in `@drawable/your_image'

Comment: This is the best way to do it. Because using R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha to change color has risks, as support version changes the drawable resource frequently.

Answer (score 254):

You can add a style to your styles.xml,

```
<style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
  <!-- Customize color of navigation drawer icon and back arrow --> 
  <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/toolbar_color_control_normal</item>
</style>
```

and add this as theme to your toolbar in toolbar layout.xml using **app:theme**, check below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme" >
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Would be better to call it ToolbarTheme though

Comment: For me <style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"> worked. My main app theme is <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">

Comment: Adding this attribute `<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/toolbar_color_control_normal</item>` to the app's main theme also works for me. You just need to ensure the Toolbar declaration uses the app's main theme

Answer (score 96):

Here is the simplest way of achieving Light and Dark Theme for Toolbar.You have to change the value of `app:theme` of the Toolbar tag

- For **Black Toolbar Title** and **Black Up arrow**, your toolbar should implement following theme:

> app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"

[image: Black Toolbar Title and Up Arrow]

- For **White Toolbar Title** and **White Up arrow**, your toolbar should implement following theme:

> app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat"

[image: White Toolbar Title and Up Arrow]

Comment: For white Toolbar Title and White Up arrow, use following theme: android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"

Comment: @ch3tanz Are you using ActionBar or Toolbar? Why do you use ActionBar styles?

Comment: @f470071 I am using Toolbar. It's just style which will support in all the versions. You can use Material Design styles if your app is targeting above Lollipop.

Comment: `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` in my case.

Answer (score 45):

Use this:

```
<style name="BaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
  <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item> 
</style>
```

Answer (score 41):

For white Toolbar Title and White Up arrow, use following theme:

```
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
```

Answer (score 16):

Just use the `MaterialToolbar` and override the default colors:

```
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"
        android:theme="@style/MyThemeOverlay_Toolbar"
        ..>
```

with:

```
  <style name="MyThemeOverlay_Toolbar" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary">
    <!-- color used by navigation icon and overflow icon -->
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/...</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

If you are using the `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar` or the `MaterialToolbar`  with the default style (`Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar`) you can use:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:theme="@style/MyThemeOverlay_Toolbar2"
```

with:

```
  <style name="MyThemeOverlay_Toolbar2" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary">
    <!-- This attributes is used by title -->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>

    <!-- This attributes is used by navigation icon and overflow icon -->
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/secondaryColor</item>
  </style>
```

Answer (score 10):

You don't have to change style for it. After setting up your toolbar as actionbar, You can code like this

```
android.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
android.getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.back);
//here back is your drawable image
```

But You cannot change color of back arrow by this method

Answer (score 7):

You can use your own icon by using `app:navigationIcon` and for the title color `app:titleTextColor`

Example:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_white_24dp"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/white" />
```

Comment: This worked for me just set any icon using this line `app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_back_black"`

Comment: didnt work for me. The color of back button or navigation icon stayed the same

Answer (score 7):

To style the Toolbar on Android 21+ it's a bit different.

```
<style name="DarkTheme.v21" parent="DarkTheme.v19">
        <!-- toolbar background color -->
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/color_primary_blue_dark</item>
        <!-- toolbar back button color -->
        <item name="toolbarNavigationButtonStyle">@style/Toolbar.Button.Navigation.Tinted</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Toolbar.Button.Navigation.Tinted" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Button.Navigation">
        <item name="tint">@color/color_white</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 6):

I think if theme should be generated some problem but its dynamically set black arrow.So i Suggested try this one.

```
Drawable backArrow = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
backArrow.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.md_grey_900), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(backArrow);
```

Comment: How your solution differs from @Parth Bhayani?

Answer (score 6):

If you want white back button (←) and white toolbar title, follow this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Change theme from `Dark` to `Light` if you want black back button (←) and black toolbar title.

Answer (score 6):

I did it this way using the Material Components library:

```xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/AppTheme.DrawerArrowToggle</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.DrawerArrowToggle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 6):

I am using `<style name="BaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar>` theme in my android application and in NoActionBar theme, `colorControlNormal` property is used to change the color of navigation icon default Back button arrow in my toolbar

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="BaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
  <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/your_color</item> 
</style>
```

Comment: not working with daynight

Answer (score 4):

Programmatically we can achieve using below code. No need to add our own back icon as suggested by many others.

```
private void initToolBar(String title) {
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle(title);
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gold));
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    // add back arrow to toolbar
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        Drawable nav = toolbar.getNavigationIcon();
        if(nav != null) {
            nav.setTint(getResources().getColor(R.color.gold));
        }
    }
}
```

Please note `toolbar.getNavigationIcon()` if requested before `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` it won't work.

Answer (score 3):

You can add this code into your java class. But you must create a vector asset before, so you can customize your arrow back.

```java
actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_black_24dp);
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple and no Worries

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:titleTextColor="@color/white"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/testing" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

For white Toolbar Title and White Up arrow, use following theme:

```
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using `navigationIconTint` property is used to change the color of navigation icon default Back button arrow in my toolbar

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme.ToolbarStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Surface">
      <item name="titleCentered">true</item>
      <item name="titleTextColor">?attr/colorOnSurface</item>
      <item name="navigationIconTint">?attr/colorOnSurface</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want **system back color** in white then you can use this code

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_notification"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp">

            <include layout="@layout/action_bar_notification" />
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

**Note:-** `android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"` is key

The paste is in your activity where you want to show back button on action bar

```
final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_notification);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```