# Action Bar black back arrow issue

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Although I'm using dark action bar, back arrow color is black.

I declared theme as below in manifest :

```
  android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar
```

and screenshot : [image]

Back arrow color should be white. How can I do this ?

Comment: I think the answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33339983/2413303 you need to use `Dark` instead of `Light` I guess.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to set your own indicator

```
<style name="Example.Theme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" >
      <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/up_indicator</item>
</style>
```