# Android: how to change color of back button, font family and text size of title in material tool bar?

Tags: android, android-toolbar, back-button, material-components-android

I am using a custom material toolbar (showing a back button and activity's title) in my activity. I would like the back button and title to be black in color.

This activity's navigation and status bar (battery, time) is currently immersive. I have tried overriding the default color using material tool bar method using the link below but its not working. The back button is still white in color. And I am not sure why is that so. I even play around to see if the tool bar is showing me open sans, but it does not neither does the changing the textSize work.
[How to change color of Toolbar back button in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33339043/how-to-change-color-of-toolbar-back-button-in-android)

In my manifest file my activity is using the following theme.

```
<activity 
     android:name=".RegisterActivity"
     android:theme="@style/CustomActivityTheme">
</activity>
```

In my custom action_bar_layout.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"
        android:theme="@style/MyThemeOverlay_Toolbar2"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

In my color file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#00BEBA</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#00BEBA</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#F60606</color>
    <color name="appBackgroundColor">#00BEBA</color>
    <color name="textFieldColor">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

In my Style file

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/textFieldColor</item>
    </style>

 <style name="CustomActivityTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="windowNoTitle">false</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyThemeOverlay_Toolbar" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary">
        <!-- color used by navigation icon and overflow icon -->
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/textFieldColor</item>
        <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/MyThemeOverlay_Toolbar2</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyThemeOverlay_Toolbar2" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary">
        <!-- This attributes is used by title -->
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textFieldColor</item>
        <!-- This attributes is used by navigation icon and overflow icon -->
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/textFieldColor</item>
    </style>
```

In my registerActivity java code

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    Toolbar actionBar;
    int currentApiVersion;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        Log.d("TestToolBar", "inside Register Activity");

        //using custom toolbar instead of custom textView as action bar
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar_layout);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar = findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        actionBar.setTitle(R.string.RegisterActionBar);

        hideNavigationBar();

    }

    public void hideNavigationBar() {
        currentApiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        Log.d("TestToolBar", "api version is " + currentApiVersion);
        
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 21) {
            View v = this.getWindow().getDecorView();
            v.setSystemUiVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            this.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY |
                            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN |
                            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
                            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
                            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        }
    }
```

[image: tool bar image]

UPDATED.
After using setSupportActionBar(toolbar); It work. But I still need to amend my activity_register.xml. To include my action_bar_layout inside using include. If not my RegisterActivity.java cannot find my toolbar.(null exception error)

The font family can be changed by having a textview inside MaterialToolbar in action_bar_layout.xml

Comment: Your theme overlay doesn't work because your are using an ActionBar and not a Toolbar.
Use setSupportActionBar(toolbar).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there are simpler ways. In your Toolbar, add the following attribute:

```
app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarTheme"
app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_back"
```

Then in styles.xml, add

```
<style name="ToolbarThemeC" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/lato</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/lato</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/White</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
    <item name="iconTint">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:colorForeground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverFlowTheme</item>
    <item name="actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/OverFlowMenuTheme</item>
</style>
```

And whatever other attributes you want.

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me.

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        style="@style/MyToolbarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/teal_700"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_back"
        app:navigationIconTint="@color/purple_700"
        app:title="Title" />
```

MyToolbarStyle:

```
<style name="MyToolbarStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar">
    <item name="titleTextColor">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="titleCentered">true</item>
    <item name="titleTextAppearance">@style/MyTextAppearanceToolbarStyle</item>
</style>
```

MyTextAppearanceToolbarStyle:

```
<style name="MyTextAppearanceToolbarStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline6">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/public_sans_italic</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/public_sans_italic</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
</style>
```

Result

[image]